# SharePoint List item hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-2007

when I am creating new item in list  , same item url I want in list column as hyperlink to be updated when it gets created / submitted.

Is it possible, if so how?

and when we create item same time wiki page should get created in wiki library with same name of item. could you please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an eventhandler on your list where you create your items. This event handler can both insert the item url into a column of your choice and create a wiki page.

Here is some info about event handlers: http://nikhilshankarsingh.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/developing-event-handlers/